# put a value in a input text inside a ng-repeat using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="submit3(qgradecontainer)">
                    <div data-ng-repeat="qgrade in qgradecontainer">

                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Quiz #{{array[$index]}}</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label>Correct Answers</label>
                                <input type="number" min="0" max="{{array2[$index]}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of items: {{array2[$index]}}" ng-model="qgrade.score" id="sc{{$index}}">

                            </div>   

                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Controller:

```
gradingSheetSrvc.getNumOfitems($scope.qtbl).then(function(msg){
                    if(msg.data){
                        $scope.array2 = $.map(msg.data[0], function(value, index) {
                            return [value];
                        });
                        $scope.ind = $.map(msg.data[0], function(value, index) {
                            return [index];
                        }); 
                        //console.log($scope.array2[1]);
                        for(var i=1; i<=len; i++){
                                $scope.qgradecontainer.push({'id':$scope.array[i-1],'sid':id,'col':$scope.ind[i-1],'tbl':$scope.qtbl,'numofitems':$scope.array2[i-1]});
                                document.getElementById("sc"+i--).value = "Test";
                            }



                    }
                });
```

Is there any way of putting a text in a input text with this code? coz im trying to put a text using a `document.getElementById("sc").value` in the input inside my controller but i always got an error message saying that `Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Answer (score 0):

First you should never manipulate DOM in controller, and if you want to set the value like;

```
<input type="number" value="100">
```

everything else remains same just set the value attribute to your desired value

Comment: But i dont know how to pass a data inside the ng-model which is `qgrade.score`. my goal is to place an existing grade which was saved in my database then put it in the input text.